# Redmine 4.0 with Postgresql Ruby-on-Rails and Apache2-Passenger got this `x64_mingw` is not a valid platform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, apache, redmine, debian-based

I require Redmine latest version with Postgresql Ruby-on-Rails and Apache2-Passenger in my Debian Linux running in VM instance.

When setting RAIL ENV I got this error

> x64_mingw` is not a valid platform.

Installation Logs Details:

```
root@lamp-bafs:/#sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.0 apache2 subversion rake rubygems libopenssl-ruby libpgsql-ruby li

root@lamp-bafs:/# su postgres   
postgres@lamp-bafs:/$ psql  

postgres=# CREATE ROLE redmine1 LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'redmine123'NOINHERIT VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE redmine1 WITH ENCODING='UTF8' OWNER=redmine1 TEMPLATE template0;
CREATE DATABASE

postgres=# \q
postgres@lamp-bafs:/$ exit
exit
root@lamp-bafs:/# cd /tmp
root@lamp-bafs:/tmp# svn co https://svn.redmine.org/redmine/branches/4.0-stable redmine-4.0

root@lamp-bafs:/tmp#
root@lamp-bafs:/tmp#  mv redmine-4.0/ /var/lib/redmine
root@lamp-bafs:/tmp# cd /var/lib/redmine
root@lamp-bafs:/var/lib/redmine#

root@lamp-bafs:/var/lib/redmine# cd redmine-4.0     
root@lamp-bafs:/var/lib/redmine/redmine-4.0# echo "production:      
>  adapter: postgresql      
>  database: redmine1       
>  host: localhost      
>  username: redmine1       
>  password: redmine123     
>  encoding: utf8       
>  schema_search_path: public">config/database.yml      
root@lamp-bafs:/var/lib/redmine/redmine-4.0#
```

I shld run the below in my SSH Terminal,

**RAILS_ENV=production rake config/initializers/session_store.rb**

**rake generate_session_store**

**RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate**

**RAILS_ENV=production rake redmine:load_default_data**

I got this issue

```
root@lamp-bafs:/var/lib/redmine# RAILS_ENV=production rake config/initializers/session_store.rb
`x64_mingw` is not a valid platform. The available options are: [:ruby, :ruby_18, :ruby_19, :mri, :mri_18, :m
ri_19, :rbx, :jruby, :mswin, :mingw, :mingw_18, :mingw_19]
root@lamp-bafs:/var/lib/redmine# rake generate_session_store
`x64_mingw` is not a valid platform. The available options are: [:ruby, :ruby_18, :ruby_19, :mri, :mri_18, :m
ri_19, :rbx, :jruby, :mswin, :mingw, :mingw_18, :mingw_19]
root@lamp-bafs:/var/lib/redmine# RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
`x64_mingw` is not a valid platform. The available options are: [:ruby, :ruby_18, :ruby_19, :mri, :mri_18, :m
ri_19, :rbx, :jruby, :mswin, :mingw, :mingw_18, :mingw_19]
root@lamp-bafs:/var/lib/redmine# RAILS_ENV=production rake redmine:load_default_data
`x64_mingw` is not a valid platform. The available options are: [:ruby, :ruby_18, :ruby_19, :mri, :mri_18, :m
ri_19, :rbx, :jruby, :mswin, :mingw, :mingw_18, :mingw_19]
```

In my Debian Ruby version

```
 root@lamp-bafs:/var/lib/redmine# ruby -v
    ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
```

Installation detailed [log [1]](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UMe_ZJHvfeipx58FCLAyBXl9LL9UZCHpQrJy7OZMNtc/edit#gid=0)

How to solve this. I appreciate those who help to solve this.

Comment: you said that is redmine 4, but on your logs you install rails 2.3.5?. Redmine 4 is for rails 5

Comment: Redmine 4 is not compatible with Ruby 1.9.3. The error however stems from a tool old version of bundler (i.e. bundler < 1.5). This version however is explicitly checked in newer versions of Redmine. As you still get this error, you are likely using a much older Redmine version (i.e. something < 3.0.1). Please ensure that you are actually using Redmine 4.0 and that you fullfil its requirements.

Comment: It appears you have two different Redmine installations, an old version in `var/lib/redmine` and a newer version in `/var/lib/redmine/redmine-4.0`. You should sort this out first.

Comment: Thanks Holger Just, I 'll remove all redmine and try again and let you know,

Comment: Thanks Javier, I 'll install rails 5 and let you know.

Comment: @HolgerJust, I removed all Redmine installed in my Debian, Installed Redmine 1.0, But when using RAIL EVN .. I got issue highlited  in red color in my Log. Here is my installation Log https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GJvq9Ino3EwNG6OigDORDDuoHAOJd_DNBUkWPtZYqys/edit#gid=0